# Office-js API to use to change page size, Margin and Orientation

Tags: ms-word, office-js

We develop Office.js addins for Word. In this process we have a need to be able to manipulate the following properties of my Word online document programmatically(which i can change through UI now)

- Margins
- Orientation (portrait)
- Custom Page size

How can i find the APIs needed to achieve this?

Comment: In other words, we are looking for JS API for properties that are possible in VBA, VSTO to manipulate Pagelayout -  Example - options available within ActiveDocument.PageSetup    ......     like Orientation, size, margins

Answer (score 2):

These parts of the COM object model haven't (yet) been implemented in the Office JS APIs.

It would be possible to change these aspects of the Page Layout on the *closed* file, leveraging the Word Open XML file format. (These properties can't be changed by manipulating the opened files XML.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Cindy- Is it something that the product group may be implementing in near future - Could you share more details on how it is possible to change using open xml, probably some useful links?

Comment: @user5501201 I have no information about whether/when the product group will implement this. You might check on UserVoice whether there's a request and if/how the product team has replied to it. I'm currently on a mobile device, so referencing any sources is difficult, but I don't know of anything specific, right off-hand, for the Open XML, except that I did try it yesterday on a document opened in Word and it did not work on the opened docment. It will work on a closed document.

Comment: thanks - please share the resources on your availability

Comment: i found this https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/blob/master/docs/word/create-better-add-ins-for-word-with-office-open-xml.md    - but i am not sure if this can be used to edit the properties i am looking for. Any comments?

Comment: @user5501201 This is the approach I tested and confirm that it is *not* possible to chanage these properties on a document opened in Word.